# I can't transport HTML information to PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp

My HTML:

```
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body style="background:aqua;">

<?php
    $text = $_GET["text"];
    $text_html = htmlspecialchars($text);
    echo "<h1>Hi, {$text_html}</h1>";
?>

</body>
```

I want to transport and show data input from `type="text"` fields in my HTML form, into my PHP file, but the result is as per below:

> Hi, {$text_html}"; ?>

Why is the extra code showing?

This is my Source Code.

[image: Screenshot of source code.]

Comment: Does your php file has .php extension. What is your deploy environment?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a submit button. After the submit button is trigerd the if condition will be set to true and the code will execute.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body style="background:aqua;">
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
       if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
           $text = $_GET["text"];
           $text_html = htmlspecialchars($text);
           echo "<h1>Hi".$text_html."</h1>";
       }
?>

</body>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please explain HOW this answer does answer the question and why your code should work. That way the OP and future reader can understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use something (like js) to submit your form.

When you try to output a variable you should use concat of strings.

```
// this will print the variable name, not is content
echo "<h1>Hi, {$text_html}</h1>";

// Using '.' you can concat strings, so:
echo "<h1>Hi".$text_html."</h1>";
```

In this way you tell the script that you want the value of $text_html instead of print the string "$text_html"

Answer (score 0):

Hello You need to change in your form code you have to add submit button just. all other code is working fine. Just change your form code with below code.

```
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Because you need to transform data from one page to other page either via form submit or you can use Session or Cookie. but currently in your case you just need to add submit button your code work

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body style="background:aqua;">
<form action="test.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> // add submit button 
</form>                                        ////html page


on php page
<?php
       if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
           $text = $_GET["text"];
           $text_html = htmlspecialchars($text);
           echo "<h1>Hi".$text_html."</h1>";
       }
?>
```

Comment: I added submit button and changed php code. But result screen isn't change. I need another way...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background:aqua;">
    <?php        
       if(isset($_GET["submit"])){
           $text = $_GET["text"];
           $text_html = htmlspecialchars($text);
           echo "<div>Hi,".$text_html."<div>";
       }
    ?>
</body>
```